# So how did Will end up in the same room with her?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, insomnia

In the film [Insomnia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278504/), towards the end Will Dormer (Al Pacino) narrates to the hotel owner Rachel Clement (Maura Tierney) how he fabricated evidence to help convict a pedophile he was certain was guilty of murdering a child.

In the next scene we see him washing his eyes and when he comes into the room, Rachel is sleeping there:

[image]

[image]

He takes his wallet/badge from the beside. So how did Will and Rachel wind up in the same room? What did I miss here?

Answer (score 5):

Before that scene Will was just trying to sleep by covering the window and this time he even dragged a table in front of it to cover the whole light:

[image][image]

That is the time Rachel comes to Will's room due to the complains of other resident of the hotel:

[image]

And then Will told the whole story of how he fabricated evidence to help convict a pedophile he was certain was guilty of murdering a child to Rachel. When he asked for her response she said:

> **Rachel Clement:** I can't judge. There are two kinds of people in Alaska: those who were born here and those who come here to escape something. I wasn't born here.  [<sub>src</sub>](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278504/quotes/qt0222017)
>
> **Rachel Clement:** I guess it's about what you thought was right at the time. Then, what you're willing to live with. [<sub>src</sub>](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278504/quotes/qt0222032)

Which suggested she is also escaping from her past and she found Will's action justifying too and we see in the next scene that she end up in his bed. Sound quite normal, people confirming each other end up in same bed.